# Anyone know if there is a Django auditing lib to track user/record activities?

Tags: django, auditing

I need add a auditing log to my system, so all changes on some module records be saved and be used for auditing purpose, this is a system to create and manage Raffle.
I am looking for a existing lib before I try to create one myself.

Thanks

Comment: http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: nice, that looks great!